# PHP function not returning correctly

Tags: php

So basically I have an array, and I have a function that will return an array value, but it is not returning anything.

```
$skills = array("Attack");
$i = 0;
```

$hs = file_get_contents("localhost/player=".$_GET["player"]);

```
    foreach($skills as $value) {
        $hs[$i] = explode(",",$hs[$i]);
        $stats[$value]["rank"] = $hs[$i][0];
        $stats[$value]["level"] = $hs[$i][1];
        $stats[$value]["xp"] = $hs[$i][2];
        $i++;
    }

    function getSkill($skill) {
        //echo $skill;
        return $stats[$skill]["level"];
    }
```

I have tried `getSkill("Attack");` and it doesn't work;
but if I do `echo $stats["Attack"]["level"];` it works fine.

Comment: Are you missing some code? Where is the `$i` coming from?

Comment: Please indend your code correctly. This looks like you put a function within a function o_O

Comment: I am declaring $i = 0; after my array, to loop all the values in the array.

Comment: Not sure what is this doing? You are trying to explode $hs which I do not see anywhere? You have written  a function getSkill, who is calling that. Please calrify,

Comment: @chandresh_cool I am using $hs = file_get_contents to get the contents of a website, and then exploding that. I am just using "echo getSkill("Attack");" to test it.

Comment: What format is the website in? Are you parsing it correctly to begin with?

Comment: Please state ALL the code needed to understand this. Wheres the variable `$stats` comming from? above you declare `$skills`, I cant see the `$stats` and `$hs` variables anywhere.

Comment: @NaotoIda Yes, I am returning several other values and saving it to a MySQL database and it is working just fine, it's just for some reason the getSkill function is not working.

Comment: "and it doesn't work;" what does not work any error messages?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER When I try to use "echo getSkills("Attack");" it does not echo anything, if I try to convert that to an int it is 0. No error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pass the $stats array to your function so it can't know what is in it.

```
function getSkill($stats, $skill) {
   //echo $skill;
   return $stats[$skill]["level"];
}
```

and call it with `getSkill($stats,"Attack");`

Comment: Seems as if I forgot to use $stats as an argmuent for my getSkill function. This fixed it, thank you.